# XPATH: If there is element with certain value assume "phone" then get it's sibling value

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I have following case

```
...
...

<tr>
    <td class="company-info">Phone:</td>
    <td> "020 641512" <span class="provider">ABC</span></td>
</tr>
....
```

**And I want to get**

- if `<td>` has a value `Phone:` then get phone number (`020 641512`) from next `<td>`

**I have imagined something like this**

```
phone = hxs.xpath("//td/text()[contains('Phone:')]", "Not available")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With scrapy `Selector` and `SelectorList` you can [use regular expressions via their `.re()` method](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.SelectorList.re):

```
>>> hxs.xpath('//td[contains(., "Phone")]/following-sibling::td[1]').re(r'(\d[\d ]+\d)')
[u'020 641512']
>>>
```

Alternative using the new CSS selectors:

```
>>> from scrapy.selector import Selector
>>> selector = Selector(response)
>>> selector.css('td:contains("Phone") + td').re(r'(\d[\d ]+\d)')
[u'020 641512']
>>>
```

Comment: It's picking up other numeric values from the page, any idea? http://pastebin.com/dwxjMhV4

Comment: if you provide input HTML that would be helpful. In the meantime you can try `selector.css('td:contains("Phone") + td::text').re(r'(\d[\d ]+\d)')` (i.e. with a regular expression matching sequence of digits with spaces). A proper phone number matching regular expression probably needs to be smarter than what I wrote

Answer (score 1):

I think you need:

```
//td[contains(., 'Phone:')]/following-sibling::td/substring-before(substring-after(normalize-space(text()[1]), '&quot;'), '&quot;')
```

the expression above works in Xquery, if it does not work, try

```
//td[contains(., 'Phone:')]/following-sibling::td/text()[1]
```

it outputs `[space]"020 641512"`

Comment: I get Invalid XPath expression

Comment: I have edited my code. Please have a look, I guess you have to do the other string manipulations.

Comment: Instead of [u'02 855587'] i am getting weird output[u'02 855587', u'\n                \n']. Need to take only [0] from the list item.

Comment: Thanks. How can I use unicode charcters suppose: //td[contains(., 'Ärlä:')]/following-sibling::td/text()[1] in the same context.

Answer (score -1):

There also is a very helpful Firefox-plugin to figure out xpaths called Firebug, look at these [instructions](http://www.wikihow.com/Find-XPath-Using-Firebug).

Comment: barrios - I didn't asked what are the tools needed to identify XPATH in the browsers.